# How to keep spaces where they were after modifying string

Tags: java, string, buffer, java.util.scanner

So I have to get words from a text file, change them, and put them into a new text file.

The problem I'm having is, lets say the first line of the file  is

hello my name is bob

the modified result should be:

ellohay myay amenay isay bobay

but instead, the result ends up being

ellomynameisbobhay

so scanner has .nextLine() but I want to have a method that is .nextWord() or something,  so that it will recognize  something as a word until it has a space after it. how can I create this?

Answer (score 0):

nextLine() gives you the whole line.

What you should use is just next(), that will give you the next word.

Comment: Let me try that and tell you what happens

edit: I get a noSuchElement exception

Answer (score 0):

Also see String.split() or StringTokenizer if you wanted to post-process whole lines. It sound s as though in your situation just using the scanner is fine, but I though i'd mention it because I assumed you'd have just used those methods if you knew about them.